# ¿Por qué mi programa no cierra debidamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera exponer el problema que tengo con un pequeño programa que desarrolle en Python, el cual no termina de ejecutarse. Creo tener una idea del por qué no deja de ejecutarse, pero no he encontrado solución alguna. El problema consiste al ingresar a la opción **5. Ver las instrucciones nuevamente**, la cual hace que la función se llame así misma, el caso es que al darle a la opción **6. Salir del programa** no lo hace, sino que me pide que vuelva a ingresar una opción para después poder salir.

```
import datetime
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()

def hora_local():
    hora = now.strftime("%I : %M : %S %p")
    print("\nLa hora local es: ", hora)

def hora_fecha_local():
    hora_fecha = now.strftime("%I : %M : %S  %p - %B / %d / %Y")
    print("\nLa hora y fecha local es: ", hora_fecha)

def hora_Ny():
    hora_ny = now.astimezone(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours = -5))).strftime("%I : %M : %S %p")
    print("\nLa hora en New York es: ", hora_ny)

def hora_Sf():
    hora_sf = now.astimezone(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours = -8))).strftime("%I : %M : %S %p")
    print("\nLa hora en san Francisco: ", hora_sf)

def menu_Principal():

    print("Bienvenido al Reloj Mundial\
    \n\nEstas son las operaciones que puedes realizar\
    \n\n1. Ver hora.\
    \n2. Ver fecha y hora.\
    \n3. Ver la hora en New York.\
    \n4. Ver la hora en San Francisco\
    \n5. Ver las instrucciones nuevamente.\
    \n6. Salir del programa.")

    while True:
        try:
            opcion = int(input("\nIngrese opción: "))

            if opcion == 1:
                hora_local()

            elif opcion == 2:
                hora_fecha_local()

            elif opcion == 3:
                hora_Ny()

            elif opcion == 4:
                hora_Sf()

            elif opcion == 5:
                os.system("pause")
                os.system("cls")
                menu_Principal() #¿Problema?

            elif opcion == 6:
                print("\nGracias por usarnos.")
                break

            else:
                print("\nPor favor Ingrese una opción de la lista.")

        except ValueError:
            print("\nPor favor Ingrese una opción.")

#Main:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu_Principal()
```

No sé si estoy llamando mal a la función, lo cual hace que cada vez que entre en ella (a la opción 5) no me deja cerrarla hasta que salga de la anterior llamado, o no es la forma adecuada de hacer dicho llamado y por eso me genera ese conflicto. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No vas mal encaminado en cuanto a la causa del problema, simplemente has descubierto la recursividad. Cuando llamas a `menu_Principal` dentro de `menu_Principal` lo que haces es una llamada recursiva, de forma que ejecutas de nuevo la función al completo con su propio ciclo `while`. La ejecución de la función "padre" queda detenida en ese punto hasta que la llamada a la función "hija" retorne. En el momento que la ejecución de la "hija" retorne la ejecución del "padre" continuará desde el punto donde llamó a la "hija". Esta cadena se repite tantas veces como llamadas recursivas hagas. Por lo tanto, cuando ingresas la opción 5  ejecutas de nuevo la función, al pulsar 6 sales de esta segunda llamada pero vuelves a la inicial.

Para ilustrarlo algo mejor vamos a ver un ejemplo muy simple con algunos prints:

```
def foo(n):
    print("Ejecutada llamada recursiva {}.\n".format(n))

    while True:
        op = input("Ingrese una opción:\n  1- Nueva llamada recursiva.\n  2- Salir.\n\n>>> ")
        if op == '1':
            foo(n+1)
        elif op == '2':
            break

    print("Terminando llamada recursiva {}.\n".format(n))

foo(1)
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Ejecutada llamada recursiva 1.

Ingrese una opción:
  1- Nueva llamada recursiva.
  2- Salir.

>>> 1
Ejecutada llamada recursiva 2.

Ingrese una opción:
  1- Nueva llamada recursiva.
  2- Salir.

>>> 1
Ejecutada llamada recursiva 3.

Ingrese una opción:
  1- Nueva llamada recursiva.
  2- Salir.

>>> 2
Terminando llamada recursiva 3.

Ingrese una opción:
  1- Nueva llamada recursiva.
  2- Salir.

>>> 2
Terminando llamada recursiva 2.

Ingrese una opción:
  1- Nueva llamada recursiva.
  2- Salir.

>>> 2
Terminando llamada recursiva 1.
```

Lo más simple para solucionarlo es crear una cadena que contenga el menu y volver a imprimirlo en la opción 5:

```
    def menu_Principal():

        menu = ("Bienvenido al Reloj Mundial"
                "\n\nEstas son las operaciones que puedes realizar"
                "\n\n1. Ver hora."
                "\n2. Ver fecha y hora."
                "\n3. Ver la hora en New York."
                "\n4. Ver la hora en San Francisco"
                "\n5. Ver las instrucciones nuevamente."
                "\n6. Salir del programa.")

        print(menu)

        while True:
            opcion = input("\nIngrese opción: ")

            if opcion == '1':
                hora_local()

            elif opcion == '2':
                hora_fecha_local()

            elif opcion == '3':
                hora_Ny()

            elif opcion == '4':
                hora_Sf()

            elif opcion == '5':
                os.system("pause")
                os.system("cls")
                print(menu)

            elif opcion == '6':
                print("\nGracias por usarnos.")
                break

            else:
                print("\nPor favor Ingrese una opción de la lista.")
```

> **Nota:** No se si es el comportamiento esperado pero debes tener en cuanta que tal y como tienes el código la hora y fecha se toma al ejecutar el script, por lo que las funciones muestran esa hora, no actualizan con el paso del tiempo.Es decir, si ejecuto el script y al pasar 15 minutos ingreso una opción la hora mostrada no es la actual, es la de hace 15 minutos. Si no quieres que esto pase debes llamar a `datime.now` en cada función y no al inicio del script.

---

**Edición**

Con respecto a la duda que planteas sobre la línea `datetime.datetime.now()` que queda muy larga y como comentas es tedioso escribirla completa cada vez, tienes varias posibilidades, pero lo más "pythónico" creo que es:

```
# Importar la clase datetime
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now())
hora = datetime.now().strftime("%I : %M : %S %p")


# Si quieres reducir aún más puedes crear un "alias"
from datetime import datetime as dt

print(dt.now())
hora = dt.now().strftime("%I : %M : %S %p")
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Entiendo lo que me dices con respecto a la recursividad,  tenía una idea muy vana sobre ese error en esa parte, pero ahora lo entiendo mejor, y con respecto a lo de la hora, no había caído en cuenta de ello, así que gracias por aclararme ese detalle. Quisiera saber, no sé si se puede "pedir" en los comentarios, si habrá una forma más corta para utilizar datetime, ya que creo que esa parte el código está algo "largo" por decirlo vulgarmente. Gracias :D

Comment: @CamiloJc no te preocupes, si son aclaraciones sobre la propia respuesta o algún detalle directamente relacionado con la pregunta que no tenga suficiente entidad para ser una pregunta diferente es correcto usar los comentarios, de hecho están para eso. He editado la respuesta, mira al final. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, la verdad si es muy tedioso, pero con tu solución intentaré implementarla en otro caso a parte de este, gracias, y Saludos :D